# Retrieving text from on click on asp hyperlink listview VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm running into a problem on retrieving the text when user Click on the Hyperlink and pass it into the Session ID. It even doesn't stop at breakpoint when I'm trying to debug. Is it not possible to pass any text back on click in ListView? Down below is my code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="orderContent" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="orderNumbers" runat="server" NavigationURL="/demo.aspx" click="onClick();"><%(Eval("Number"))%></asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>

Public Sub onClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs)
 Dim orderTextNumber As String = CType(Me.FindControl("orderNumbers"),HyperLink).Text()
  Session.Add("Orders", orderTextNumber)
End Sub
```

Comment: The control HyperLink doesn't have a click event.  You need to use the LinkButton control if you want to use click events.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinkButton instead of a HyperLink

```
<asp:ListView ID="orderContent" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="orderNumbers" runat="server" NavigationURL="/demo.aspx" OnClick="ordersNumbers_Click"><%(Eval("Number"))%</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Get the LinkButton text and add it to the session

```
Public Sub orderNumbers_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewItemEventArgs)
   Dim orderTextNumber As String = CType(Me.FindControl("orderNumbers"),LinkButton).Text()
   Session.Add("Orders", orderTextNumber)
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not going to work because it will give 'orderNumbers' not declared.

Comment: @Kluong You are right.Forgot linkbutton is inside ListView.Edited

Comment: I have actually fixed this problem. Instead of onlick, i've used the command argument property. Thanks.